# I don't know what the error is

Tags: c, function-pointers

I wrote this code in C, to read an array of numbers then write them to the screen, but for some values of n(ex. n=6), it gives an error. What is wrong?

```
     #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int n;
void read(int *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%d",a+i);
}
void write(int *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d",*(a+i));
}
int main()
{

    int *a;
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    read(&a);
    write(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When your code does not compile without warnings, say so.  When your code does not compile without warnings, assume you've made a mistake.  Compilers don't generate warnings for fun — or to annoy novice programmers.  They generate warnings when they're sure that the code you've written isn't the code you intended to write.  Heed the warnings!  If you don't understand them, ask about the compiler warnings.  Don't pretend your code is good.  (Is there any reason to prefer `*(a+i)` over `a[i]`?  I can't think of any good ones.)

Comment: Also, for future reference, it is by far better to pass both the size of the array (the number of items in it) and the array to a function than to rely on a global variable for the size.  That is: `void read(int n, int *a)` and `void write(int n, int *a)` would be better than what you've got, and you should avoid global variables in general and ones like `n` in particular.

Comment: (Disclaimer: Not _all_ warnings are the fault of the programmer; they may indicate a flaw in the compiler and/or its support for the standard, or just be informational. This is especially true with certain compilers (such as Visual C/C++), and/or when certain compiler options (such as `-Wall`) are specified; examples include GCC's `-Wdouble-promotion` ("warning: `float` implicitly promoted to `double`") & `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` ("warning: `case` falls through in `switch` statement"), or MSVC's C4514 ("warning: I optimised an unused inline function out") & C4820 ("warning: I added padding").)

Comment: (Generally, speaking, though, they usually indicate something you'll want to look at, and probably fix.)

Comment: The title does not add anything to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `read()` and `write()` incorrectly - you should not be taking the address of what is already a pointer.

Change:

```
read(&a);
write(&a);
```

to:

```
read(a);
write(a);
```

Note that, in future, you should always **enable compiler warnings and take notice of them** - this mistake would have been immediately obvious if compiler warnings had been enabled:

```
<stdin>:21:10: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'int *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    read(&a);
         ^~
<stdin>:4:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'a' here
void read(int *a)
               ^
<stdin>:22:11: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'int *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    write(&a);
          ^~
<stdin>:9:17: note: passing argument to parameter 'a' here
void write(int *a)
                ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Can even a C90 compiler validly process the code without generating warnings?  Certainly, `gcc -std=c90 -c so-4081-2138.c` generates warnings (while generating code), and that's about as lax as you can get.  And I think the standard requires at least one such 'diagnostic' for the code.  (See also the first of my two comments to the main question.). Also, I observe that `clang` is very explicit: `warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'int *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` and pointing out the function calls.

Comment: Yes, good point - I just realised that those warnings were generated without even adding `-Wall`. And yes, `clang`'s error messages do seem to be somewhat more detailed than `gcc`'s, which can be helpful at times. Of course the OP may be using some horrible old compiler, such as Turbo C, and who knows whether that would generate appropriate warnings, given a chance ?

Answer (score -2):

Look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;

void read(int *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", (a + i));

        // don't forget to consume the rest of line until ENTER
        scanf("%*[^\n]");   // consume all caracters until the newline
        scanf("%*c");       // consume the newline
    }
}

void write(int *a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) printf("%d", *(a + i));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *a;
    printf("n= ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // don't forget to consume the rest of line until ENTER
    scanf("%*[^\n]");   // consume all caracters until the newline
    scanf("%*c");       // consume the newline

    a = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    // this is a FATAL ERROR !
    //read(&a);
    //write(&a);

    read(a);
    write(a);

    printf("\n");

    // don't forget to release memory allocated with 'malloc'
    free(a);

    return(0);
}
```

I this what you want? If so, enjoy.

Comment: @PaulR, I only post answers AFTER test the code MYSELF. In my compiler ZERO ERRORS. If you find errors in my program, please let me know what they are. But better than that, post here YOUR FULL PROGRAM for all of us learn with you. Comments are only helpful when justified with CONCRETE examples. I'm waiting for your code.

Comment: @PaulR, According to your last comment «There are more bugs in this code than in the original version». So the challange remains. Better than say that our effort is useless, is write OUR answers. Can't you write the FULL program to the OP (and me) can learn something? After all, the full program is not so big.